# Unable to start activity: null pointer exception

Tags: android

I'm developing an activity within an android application that uses the "Fixed Tabs + Swipe" model. Each 'tab' in this activity will be used for storing a different type of contact information. The first stores name, gender, mobile, date of birth etc. The next tab will store address information - and following tabs will store other information.

So on the first tab, I wanted to have a spinner that works like a 'drop-down menu' for selecting the person's title (Mr/Ms/Mrs etc). I have a string-array in my `strings.xml` defined like so:

```
<string-array name="titles">
    <item>"Mr."</item>
    <item>"Miss"</item>
    <item>"Ms."</item>
    <item>"Mrs."</item>
    <item>"Dr."</item>        
</string-array>
```

However I am trying to populate the spinner in code and I am getting a null pointer exception on the line `titleSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);`. This is my activity code:

```
public class ModifyCustActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

private static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;
private static final int DATE_DIALOG = 0;

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_modify_cust);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
    setupTitleSpinner();
}

private void setupTitleSpinner() {      
    Spinner titleSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnTitle);       
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.titles, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    titleSpinner.setAdapter(adapter); // EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.modify_cust, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return fragment = new FragmentCustBasic();
        case 1:
            return fragment = new FragmentCustAddress();
        default:
            break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Basic";
        case 1:
            return "Address";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static class FragmentCustBasic extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public FragmentCustBasic() {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_modify_cust_basic, container, false);
                return rootView;
    }
}

public static class FragmentCustAddress extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public FragmentCustAddress() {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_modify_cust_address, container, false);
                return rootView;
    }
}

public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_modify_cust_basic, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

This is the xml for the activity:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/androidbg_dark"
    tools:context=".ModifyCustActivity" />
```

And here is the xml file for one of the fragments (the one in question - with the spinner on it):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ModifyCustActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtFirstName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/fname"
        android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

        <requestFocus />
       </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtLastName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtFirstName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/lname"
        android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMobileNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLastName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/mobile"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtMobileNumber"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/dob"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDate"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my logcat output:

```
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.ModifyCustActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at com.example.myapp.ModifyCustActivity.setupTitleSpinner(ModifyCustActivity.java:102)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at com.example.myapp.ModifyCustActivity.onCreate(ModifyCustActivity.java:93)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
08-01 11:33:02.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10461):    ... 11 more
```

I am new to android development.

Comment: what is on ModifyCustActivity.java at line 102?

Comment: Check your menifest.xml is that FragmentActivity registered or not..

Comment: @MocialovBoris `titleSpinner.setAdapter(adapter); // EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE`

Comment: @Pradeep Yes the activity is registered in manifest :)

Comment: @Teifi is the xml posted `activity_modify_cust.xml`?

Comment: Are you sure you are inflating/using right layouts everywhere?

Comment: @Teifi i guess you have the spinner in a different xml than `activity_modify_cust.xml`. Is the xml posted `activity_modify_cust.xml`? or is it different? you have a view pager i don't see that in the posted xml

Comment: The xml posted was the *fragment* xml which is one of the tabs on the page, where the spinner is located. I have edited the question to provide the xml for the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am encountering this problem because the views I am trying to access are contained in a separate fragment xml file. I have asked a separate question about how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994077/use-view-from-fragment-xml-file#17994222). Thanks for your responses guys.

Answer (score 0):

Where is ViewPager View in your activity_modify_cust.xml. then you are trying to get viewId which is not in xml file. given below

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

// So this line giving you null pointer exception

Comment: ops mentions exception occurs @ `titleSpinner.setAdapter(adapter)`;

Answer (score 0):

You should decleare spinner global:

so

```
public class ModifyCustActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

  Spinner spinner;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_modify_cust);
     spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnTitle);
      .....
     setupTitleSpinner();

  }
  private void setupTitleSpinner() {      

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.titles, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter); // spinner is now global
 }
}
```

Because you're trying to access to data that isn't defined.. Because your findViewById can find items just because you've decleared the "setContentView"

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion, I've made it global (and will make others global too, now that I know) - but unfortunately that did not solve the issue. I am still getting a null pointer exception, this time when calling `setupTitleSpinner()`

Comment: @Teifi you have setcontentview of one xml but initializing spinner which is in another xml. its obvious you get NPE

Comment: @Raghunandan Obvious to you maybe but as I said in my question I am new to android. I have many XML files to be used in this activity, do I need to setContentView to all of them?

Comment: @Teifi you can `findviewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity. Your `activity_cust_modify` does not have a spinner

Comment: @Raghunandan Could you explain how to do this in an answer? I would appreciate it very much

Comment: @Teifi how to do what? if you have a layout you can set the content to the activity and initialize views in that layout. If you have a fragment you can inlfate a view and intialize views of the inflated layout. but you cannot intialize views that are in a different xml file liek what you just did

Comment: @Raghunandan What I'm trying to do is control a spinner that is in another xml file (because this activity has lots of fragments - lots of different tabs). I'm just looking for a quick example on how to do this, as I'm having trouble understanding your response :(

Comment: @Teifi what your trying to do is not possible. the answer is a simple NO.