# Use view from fragment xml file

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with several tabs (using the 'fixed tabs + swipe' style). Each tab layout is defined as a fragment xml file.

Eg, my activity is called `ModifyCustActivity`. This uses an almost-empty xml file called `activity_modify_cust.xml`. Each tab on this page is represented by various xml files such as `fragment_modify_cust_basic` and `fragment_modify_cust_address` etc etc. Each of these fragment xml files contains `EditText`s, `Spinner`s and more.

When the activity starts, I need to be able to access these views from the activity code, as I need to pre-populate them, and get their results once they are edited. However, because these views exist in a fragment xml file, I don't seem to be able to reach them in code. Is there a way to access a view contained in a fragment xml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to access a view contained in a fragment xml file?

Yes it is, but your fragment should be declared in the XML layout file, which seems to be your case.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              ...">

    <fragment
            android:name="com.example.MyFragment"
            android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And you would access the fragment like this:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment)manager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment);
```

Then using the `fragment` instance you could further access your views, for example by calling a public method from the fragment which updates some particular view.

**UPDATE:**
Suppose you have a `TextView` that appears in layout of the fragment, and need to update from the activity.

Let this be the fragment class:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, null, false);
        textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        return view;
    }

    public void updateTextView(String text){
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Then you would update the `TextView` by calling in your activity the `updateTextView()` method:

```
fragment.updateTextView("text");
```

Comment: Thanks Andy. I actually just noticed it. Sorry for my stupidity there.

Comment: Just one more thing, could you expand the code a little bit just to give an example of how I could reference a view inside a fragment in a little more detail? I'm a bit stuck :(

Comment: Thank you Andy. Clearly I need to learn more about fragments as this is confusing the hell out of me! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach fragments views from activity. If you want to send a data from fragment to another fragment. Your sender fragment must communicate with activity and your activity can manipulate the view in other fragment

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html