# Use a view from a fragment in main activity

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm pretty new in android development and I have some questions about communication between fragments and main activity.

I didn't success to solve my problem in my particular case. What I want to do is to modify the alpha of a view inside a fragment (something like a card) when scrolling from one fragment to the one with this view. I tried different things but I failed (null pointer exception), you can see some experiments in a comment. Here is my code and my architecture:

Fragment with the view:

```
public class  VideoviewFragment extends BaseFragment {

/* public View card;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_videoview, container, false);
    card = (View) rootview.findViewById(R.id.card_video);
    return rootview;
}

 public void setalphacard(float value){
    card.setAlpha(value);
}*/


public static VideoviewFragment create() {

    return new VideoviewFragment();
}

@Override
public int getLayoutResId() {
    return R.layout.fragment_videoview;
}

@Override
public void inOnCreateView(View root, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


}
}
```

Base fragment:

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

private View mRoot;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRoot = inflater.inflate(getLayoutResId(), container, false);
    inOnCreateView(mRoot, container, savedInstanceState);
    return mRoot;
}

@LayoutRes
public abstract int getLayoutResId();

public abstract void inOnCreateView(View root, @Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState);
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Viewpager
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.am_view_pager);
    final MainPagerAdapter adapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // tabview et viewpager
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    // Changement couleurs swipe
    viewPager.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(135,206,250));

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            if(position == 1) {

                viewPager.setBackgroundColor((Integer) new ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(positionOffset, Color.rgb(135,206,250),Color.rgb(240,15,45)));
                //videoviewFragment.setalphacard(positionOffset);

            }

            if(position == 0) {

                viewPager.setBackgroundColor((Integer) new ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(positionOffset, Color.TRANSPARENT,Color.rgb(135,206,250)));

            }

            }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

     switch (position){

         case 0:
             return CameraFragment.create();
         case 1:
             return OptionFragment.create();
         case 2:
             return VideoviewFragment.create();
     }

     return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

XML VideoviewFragment

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout0"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
    android:id="@+id/card_video"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_background_video"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

(I know there is no instance of my fragment in this activity...)
I found few similar topics on StackOverflow like this one [Use view from fragment xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994077/use-view-from-fragment-xml-file), but I'm doing something wrong...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you include your MainAdapter code?

Comment: "when scrolling from one fragment to the one with this view", do you want to send the view from one fragment to other?

Comment: No, I just want the view in 'VideoviewFragment' became more opaque with scrolling

Comment: Did you have a look at https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#viewpager ? It talks about applying transformations to the pages.

Comment: ok guys i found everything i need on this page https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter, thanks!